# [Android source code learning ]How does IMediaRecorder.cpp do the Muxer job?

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder, mediamuxer

I want to extract the media muxer part from the `MediaRecorder.java`.

I've been reading the android source code, the version is Jellybean(4.2.2). The corresponding is `android_media_MediaRecorder.cpp` and`MediaRecoder.cpp`, however, there is no clear definition of media muxer process in the `start()` function. 
So I read the `IMediaRecorder.cpp` , but there is still no clear definition:

```
status_t start()
{
ALOGV("start");
Parcel data, reply;
data.writeInterfaceToken(IMediaRecorder::getInterfaceDescriptor());
remote()->transact(START, data, &reply);
return reply.readInt32();
}
```

I don't know what to look at now... Does anyone know about this??
Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found some useful article.

Class MPEG4Writer is doing this job, and you can find a MPEG4Writer.cpp in the source code.

Comment: where did you find this article? I was actually curious of the relationship between MPEG4Writer.cpp and methods used in the MediaPlayer class such as setting orientation hint? Can I also read that article you found?